# Как работает метод send()?

Tags: php, while, генераторы

```
  <?php
  function block()
  {
    while(true) {
      $string = yield;
      echo $string;
    }
  }
  $block = block();
  $block->send("Hello, world!<br />");
  $block->send("Hello, PHP!<br />");
?>
```

В документации написано, что он передает значение в генератор. Можете подробнее описать, как это происходит? Непонятно, что проверяет цикл `while()` и как `$string` получает переданную строку.

Comment: цикл `while` ничего не проверяет, это обычный бесконечный цикл. `send` устанавливает значение `yield`, т.е. текущее значение генератора, вот и записывается оно в переменную в строке `$string = yield`.

Comment: Как именно оно записывается в переменную string? Интересует сам процесс. Вот дошел он до строки $string = yield и?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Непонятно, что проверяет цикл `while()`

ничего не проверяет, выполняет бесконечный цикл, чтобы вызывать `send` можно было произвольное число раз.

При вызове `send` генератор доходит выполняется до первого вызова `yield`, потом проходит следующую итерацию и останавливается перед новым вызовом. Параметр переданный в `send()` становится новым значением генератора. Т.е мы явно указываем новое значение, и проводим итерацию цикла.
сама переменная `$string` в данном случае для работы не нужна, генератор может выглядеть просто как

```
while(true) echo yield;
```

В документации как раз и описано. что при вызове `send` оператор `yield` вернет переданное значение, а при вызове `next()` вернет `null`. В более классической форме мы наоборот в цикле сами устанавливаем значение `yield $value`.

> Как именно оно записывается в переменную `$string`? Интересует сам процесс. Вот дошел он до строки `$string = yield` и?

Согласно документации, при первом вызове генератор сначала выполняется до места где первый раз встречается `yield`, далее происходит установка текущего значения генератора.  Мы это значение передаем явно в параметре `send`, то есть в данном месте значение генератора будет установлено.
Сам по себе оператор `yield` (некий аналог `return`) возвращает это самое текущее значение, которое и возвращается в переменную `string`. То есть:

1. дошли до первого `yield`
2. установили текущее значение
3. присвоили его переменной (если вас смущает сама запись `$string = yield`), то представьте ее в виде `$string = $this->current();`
4. вывели строку
5. завершили итерацию и остановились перед следующим `yield`.

собственно добавив немного отладочного вывода можно эту цепочку проследить:

```
function block()
{

  echo "first run!\n";
  while(true) {
      echo "----- before yield\n";
      echo yield;
      echo " ---- after yield\n";
  }
}

$block = block();
echo "------------- call send()\n";
$block->send("Hello, world!\n");

echo "------------- call send()\n";
$block->send("Hello, PHP!\n");
```

на выходе получим

```
-- call send()
----- first run!
----- before yield
Hello, world!
---- after yield
----- before yield

-- call send()
Hello, PHP!
---- after yield
----- before yield
```

Comment: А при втором вызове метода send() продолжается выполнения метода со строки $string = yield, на котором остановилось выполнение предыдущего метода? И остановилось оно из-за отсутствия значения, да?

Comment: И по поводу цикла while(). Почему без него мы не можем вызвать метод с другим значением?

Comment: @Мирон можем, почему нет? Генератор будет выполняться (с остановками) до тех пор. пока встречается `yield`. В случае с `while(true)` его можно будет вызывать бесконечное число раз. В противном случае, количество вызовов будет конечно. Можете тело генератора заменить на `echo yield; echo yield;` и тогда третий вызов генератор уже не приведет ни к каким действиям, поскольку генерируемых значений только 2.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что если мы уберем цикл while, то второй вызов метода не выполнится.

Comment: вроде того (фактически метод будет запущен, но где-то в недрах реализации сразу произойдет выход)

Comment: Все, понял. Спасибо, что уделили время)